# Argument of type 'HTMLButtonElement | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Element | Node | Document | Window

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library

I've got this code:

```
  const { queryByText } = renderView();
  const element = queryByText(constants.SUBMIT_BUTTON_TEXT) as HTMLSpanElement;

  fireEvent.click(element.closest("button"));
```

And this error:

*(method) Element.closest<"button">(selector: "button"): HTMLButtonElement | null (+2 overloads)
Returns the first (starting at element) inclusive ancestor that matches selectors, and null otherwise.
Argument of type 'HTMLButtonElement | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Element | Node | Document | Window'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Element | Node | Document | Window'.ts(2345)*

My tests are passing but I would love to solve an error in `element.closest("button")`

if I use any instead of HTMLSpanElement, the error will go.
but I want avoid using any,  assigning HTMLButtonElement doesn't solve the problem as well

this is what I get when I console log element

```
   HTMLSpanElement {
    '__reactInternalInstance$4tax0rxao1s':
     FiberNode {
       tag: 5,
       key: '.0',
       elementType: 'span',
       type: 'span',
       stateNode: [Circular],
       return:
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it working using getByTestId

https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/bytestid